# Hot to construct dynamic language variable

Tags: javascript, variables

I have this language array:

```
var messages = {
adult1:'Adult',
adult2:'Adults'
}
```

and this function

```
//id = 'adult';
//v = 2;

function changer(id,v){
var label = '';
label = eval(id+v);
console.log(messages.label);
//I want to see 'Adults' label
}
```

but the result is ReferenceError: adult2 is not defined

How can I concate both variables and create a new one that will print the variable from messages array

Thank you in advance

Comment: Don't, use bracket notation to look up the property you need instead

Comment: can you please give me example with my code, thanks

Comment: Why you closed my question mate, that dublicate is not helping at all !

Comment: When you have a string and you want to look up a property of an object, where the property is that string, use bracket notation - eg `obj[foo + bar]` will look up whatever property is the `foo` variable concatenated with the `bar` variable. The same thing will work here